# ViewName Returned is Empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am performing a unit test and checking if my controller action returns the correct view but for some reason it is always returning empty string.

```
  [When(@"when I go to the search page")]
        public void WhenTheUserGoesToTheSearchScreen()
        {
            _controller = new HomeController();
            _result = _controller.Search(); 
        }

        [Then(@"the search view should be displayed")]
        public void ThenTheSearchViewShouldBeDisplayed()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Search",(_result as ViewResult).ViewName); // ViewName is empty!
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ViewName` property will always be empty unless you pass the string name of the view when its returned from your controller action, I.E:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    return View("Search");
}
```

If you just return `View()` then ViewName will be an empty string. It's annoying (especially when using MVContrib) but it is what it is.

Comment: It's actually a good thing. An empty view name means the default view associated with the action was invoked. If the name was filled out for default views, it'd be harder to make that distinction.

Comment: I forgot to ask that what is then a good way to make sure that the correct view is returned from the controller when unit testing!

Comment: @Matt I see your point. I was mostly frustrated when I first learned .NET did that and had just spent a while refactoring all my controllers to be fluent via MvcContrib and was no longer using any string based names. I know there's better ways to test fluent controllers but that's a different topic = )

Comment: @john that's a separate question then what you've asked above. I'd recommend closing this one and then asking it in another question.